# One to One Weak Entity Mapping JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Entity Class

```
@Entity
Class Search
{ 
   @Id
   private Long SearchID;
   private String Type;

}
```

and another Entity Class ( SearchResults which is a weak Entity that depends on Search Class for its Primary Key

```
@Entity

Class SearchResults

{
   @???
   private Long SearchID;
}
```

What annotation should i use to assign "SearchID" of "Search" Entity class as my primary key in my weak Entity " SearchResults"

Comment: If the SearchResults table has a SearchID column, why not just use `@Id` too? Otherwise, you should give us more info about these tables..

Comment: But my "searchID" in "SearchResults" depends on  "SearchID" of Search Class.

Answer (score 3):

Using the JPA concept of Shared Primary Key, you can map your relationship as follows:

Your main class:

```
@Entity
public class Search { 
   @Id
   private Long searchID;
   private String type;
}
```

**Derived Identifier with Single Attribute**

```
@Entity
public class SearchResults {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEARCHID")       
    private Search search;
}
```

**Deriver Identifier with Shared Mappings**

```
@Entity
public class SearchResults {
    @Id
    private Long searchID;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEARCHID")       
    private Search search;
}
```

Full article here: http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com.br/2014/05/onetoone-with-shared-primary-key.html

Comment: In order for this solution to work is necessary to set search property, as it is on the newInstance static creator of the example, otherwise the searchID of SearchResults will be null when trying to save its master Search object.

Comment: @MiguelSlv you actually mean to save it by saving new instance of `SearchResults` class  also with `searchID` property? For example: `SearchResults newInstance = new SearchResults();  newInstance.setSearchID(searchID); ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

SearchResult does not have to be an entity.

While it can be mapped as an Enity with a shared PK as suggested in the other answer, as a Weak entity it cannot exist independently of its associated Search and so can be mapped as an Embeddable.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables

```
@Entity
public class Search
{ 
    @Id
    private Long SearchID;

    private String Type;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(....)
    private Set<SearchResults> results;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class SearchResults
{
    //does not need an Id

    //other fields
}
```