# Shared primary key but want to manage/save entities separately?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Note : I am a hibernate newbie.

I am currently trying to model 2 entities in spring that have the same primary key and a OneToOne relationship.

Table 1 :

```
CREATE TABLE person (
id uuid NOT NULL,
name varchar(10000),
CONSTRAINT pk_person_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Table 2 :

```
CREATE TABLE nickname (
id uuid NOT NULL,
nick varchar(10000),
CONSTRAINT pk_nickname_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_person_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Java classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "person")
public class NickName {

  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "nick")
  private String nick;

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private Person person;
}
```

1) The behavior I want is to allow saving objects of Person class separately ie not save them as part of the call to save Nickname.

2) For a subset of Persons, I may wish to create a Nickname. Each person in this hypothetical example can only have one nickname.

3) When saving nicknames, I don't want the person object to also be saved. It may be that the person may exist beforehand and the nickname is added later. I currently get an exception regarding the entity already existing when trying to save Nickname object via NicknameRepository.save(nickname) where nickname object is initialized with nick and person objects, in the case that the person already exists.

4) I do want the primary key ids to be the same, and the id being a foreign key from Nickname --> Person

5) I don't want to save or add the nickname when saving the person object either.

6) When adding a nickname for an existing person, i would rather pass just the id of the Person instead of the entire object. Currently, I am forced to pass the Person object in its entirety.

Would be great if somebody could help!

Comment: Is there a reason you need to set it up this way? If you're going to use a relational database, you would be better off using a seperate table for Nickname entities with a primary key which is also a foreign key, and this will be the id of the Person it belongs to in the Person table. (Called a weak entity, since the primary key of Nickname relies on the existence of a Person with the same id)

Comment: ^ That is exactly the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead with the following which served my requirements.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private NickName nickName;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "nickname")
public class NickName {

  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "nick")
  private String nick;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576986/4364101) gives a good example of how to do it.
For you it'll be something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "Person")
public class Person {
  @Id
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="person")
  private NickName nickname;
}
```

And your other class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "NickName")
public class NickName {

  @Id
  @Column(name="person_id")
  private UUID id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
  private Person person;

  @Column(name = "nick")
  private String nick;

}
```

If you're starting off with hibernate, I'd advise keeping [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) bookmarked, it's a good cheat sheet for mapping relations (one-to-many etc) to hibernate entities.

Also look into cascade types once you understand that to make sure your entities persist and delete the way you expect! If you're using spring, even writing unit tests for your repositories is a really good way to make sure it works how you think it does.

Here's a quick example of how you can test that (if you're using repositories and Spring):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest // sets up an in memory h2 database
public class RepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void createUser() {
        User user = new User("somethingelse.com", "hello")
        user = userRepository.save(user);

        entityManager.flush(); // This forces the transaction to occur

        assertEquals(userCount + 1, userRepository.findAll().size());

        assertEquals(user, userRepository.findByEmail("somethingelse.com").get());
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an exception on the class NickName saying:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class <package>.Nickname] does not define an IdClass

Comment: @redshadow updated, found an example from one of my own projects so that should definitely work!